# Resolvent norm for an inhomogeneous equation

Tags: functional-analysis

I have this problem

Let

$$R_\lambda = |P-I\lambda|^{-1}$$

be the resolvent norm of some operator $P$ and $\lambda$ be its eigenvalues (the exponential coefficients of the eigenfunctions, $\psi(x)$ of *P*).
Let $\psi(x) \in L^2$, and let $P$ be the following bounded operator on the space $J=[a,b]$:

$$P:= \frac{d^2}{dx^2}+V(x)$$

which is the Schrödinger operator for the homogeneous Schrödinger equation:

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+V(x)=0$$

With the following expression we can calculate the resolvent norm for the operator:

$$R_\lambda\bigg|_a^b = |P\psi(a)-\lambda\psi(a)|^{-1}-|P\psi(b)-\lambda\psi(b)|^{-1}$$

provided $V(x)$ is defined and bounded on $J=[a,b]$.

Now, let us consider the inhomogeneous Schrödinger equation:

$$\bigg(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+V(x)\bigg)\psi(x)=f(x)$$

where $f(x)$ is some force function.

My question is , is the resolvent norm the same for this inhomogeneous problem or is the force function included in the resolvent norm calculations?

Comment: I learned from a colleague that $R_\lambda=|P-I\lambda|^{-1}$ for inhomogeneous and homogeneous equations. It is the operator which is evaluated against the eigenfunction. Naturally, one has to find the eigenfunctions first. So the answer to the question is that the  resolvent norm is calculated equally for both cases, however, the eigenfunction it is evaluated against will differ between the homogeneous and inhomogenous case.